# Program 'flask.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

i am learning flask from a course in udemy, i followed the steps by changing:

1. run Pycharm as adminstrator (on Python 3.10 interpreter)
2. changed main.py to hello.py
3. put the code as shown in the picture and input the following; set FLASK_ etc. as shown in the picture at local terminal, i tried other solutions like $ and % flask run but it always give me Access is denied as shown. How do i proceed? really need your help as i searched and this is my last resort now..

the error code is:

```
Program 'flask.exe' failed to run: Access is denied

At line:1 char:1
 flask run

 CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: Try `python -m flask run` as an alternative.

Comment: @toyotaSupra apologises, see as edited

Comment: @AKX, THANK YOU SO MUCH, i run that in Command Prompt Terminal instead of local and it worked, is there a difference in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `flask.exe` shim created when installing `flask` is access-denied for you.

`python -m flask` does the same thing (in this case!), so you can use that as a substitute.